# Parsing excel directory with pandas to mssql with filename substrings column

Tags: sql-server, pandas, pandasql

I have a folder with subfolders stacked with .xls files which I want to merge into one large DataFrame and export it to a mssql server. Furthermore the filenames contains a timestamp ddmmmyyyy which I need to extract and concatenate to the df.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os, pymssql, pyodbc
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def connect():
    return pyodbc.connect(
        r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
        r'SERVER=myServer;'
        r'DATABASE=myDB;'
        r'UID=myUser;'
        r'PWD=myPwd;'
        r'TDS_Version=7.3;'
        r'Port=1337'
        )
cnx = create_engine('mssql://', creator=connect)

cnx.connect()

# Parse files and dump to SQL
folder = "\myFolder\""

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".xls") and ("~" not in file):
        df = pd.read_excel(root + "/" + file,header=5)
        tmp  = file.split("_")[2]
        tmp  = datetime.strptime(tmp, '%d%b%Y')
        df['Created'] = tmp
        df.to_sql(name="myTable", con=cnx, if_exists='append', index=False)

# Check the dumped content
sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, cnx)

df.head()
```

The connection works, and from what I gather the loop runs, but no new data are added to the DataFrame. `df.head()` returns an unchanged table. Someone got any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Also I get this annoying connection warning when running the create_engine statement, although it doesn't affect anything:

> SAWarning: No driver name specified; this is expected by PyODBC when
>   using DSN-less connections   "No driver name specified;

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: what do you see if you add `print(df.head(2))` just before `df.to_sql(...)`?

Comment: it returns the 2 two head rows from the first excel file in the directory. So it seems somehow it doesn't append new iterations of the df to the table?  I also included a `I = I +1` at the bottom of the loop, and it show zero when the iterations are done. must have messed up the loop somewhere...

Comment: did you check the # of rows in SQL Server table before and after executing this script?

Comment: yes, no change.